# In the AEM Query Builder API is it possible to query the properties of a related resource?

Tags: aem, query-builder

We have some code in AEM that currently allows us to search a folder of content fragments and then interrogate nested content fragments based on their jcrName.

So, take for example a CF named "FAQ". And that fragment has a related fragment named "Question Type". We can search for FAQs with a Question Type like "Day of the procedure".

In GraphQL currently we can search the field questionType and ask if the jcrName matches "day-of-the-procedure" even if what's actually set in JCR is the path to the questionType fragment.

I'm struggling to figure out how to do something similar in Query Builder outside of either using SQL2 or making an initial query that retrieves the jcrName values from the questionType fragment.

Am I missing something?

Comment: *"do something similar in Query Builder outside"* - as in to access the JCR Repository or to have similar API on non-AEM solution? if its for the latter [JCR has an open source implementation](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/jcr-api.html) so you can make your own implementation.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same logic, but inside Query Builder for the sake of performance.